# Test spring based rest service with JerseyTest and Grizzly: dependency injection not working

Tags: spring, jersey

Here my Rest WS:

```
@Path("/personService")    
@Service
public class PersonRestService {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonRestService.class);

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Person getPersonByID(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    logger.debug("getItemByID with id {}", id);
    return personService.getPersonById(id);
}
```

Here is the unit test:

```
   public class PersonServiceRestTest extends JerseyTest {

     public PersonServiceRestTest() throws Exception {
        super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.intesasanpaolo.web.rest.service").
                contextPath("test")
                .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath*:application-context/web-test-context.xml")
                .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .build());
     }


@Test
public void testGetPerson() {
    Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:9998/test/personService/1");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
    System.out.println(response);

}
```

}

When I run the test I receive and exception on personService.getPersonById(id) since personService is not autowired.
It seems that all the rest services created by grizzly do not share the spring context defined above:

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.intesasanpaolo.web.rest.service
10-feb-2014 19.10.01 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.intesasanpaolo.web.rest.service.PersonRestService
  class com.intesasanpaolo.web.rest.service.MyResource
```

I read a lot of discussion but still no solution.
Any idea?
Kind regards.
Massimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.
The context was not shared because the WebAppDescriptor was not configured with the SpringServlet.

The working configuration is the following.

```
super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("com.intesasanpaolo.web.rest.service")
                .contextPath("test")
                .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath*:application-context/web-test-context.xml")
                .servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
                .initParam("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true")
                .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
                .build());
```

Hope this could help someone ;)
Max